# Understanding curl request

Tags: curl

I got following line along with the response. How to force that connection is closed after the response?

> Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

curl command:

`curl -v --user uname:password -H "Accept: application/xml" http://localhost:8090/services/VariableService/variableService/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, curl keeps connection for 60 sec. Use curl -v --user uname:password -H "Accept: application/xml" http://localhost:8090/services/VariableService/variableService/ **--no-keepalive** to negate the default behavior.